# Mysql group by some field non distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some task.
I need to get this table. It consist of two tables. where table_2.name not distinct.
Please help me to make this query. Thanks!

```
id   name1  id  name2
1    Alex    2  Alexander
2    Alex    3  Alexan
4    Vlad    5  Vladimir
5    Vlad    6  Vladik
```

From two tables.

```
Table_1
id   name
1     Alex
2     Pit
3     Vlad
```

And 
Table_2

```
   id id_table_1 real_name
   1      1     Alexander
   2      1     Alexan
   3      2     Piter
   4      3     Vladimir
   5      3     Vladik
```

my query

```
select table_1.name,table_2.id,table_2.real_name
from table_1 join table_2
where table_1.id = table_2.id_table_1
```

Comment: Show us, what you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Why in your output table Alex has id=2, and Pit is missing?

Comment: Can you prepare sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/?

Answer (score 1):

if all you want is to combine duplicated rows, use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

If you need to combine rows that are duplicate in some columns, use `GROUP BY` but you need to to specify what to do with the other columns. You can either omit them (by not listing them in the SELECT clause) or aggregate them (using functions like SUM, MIN, and AVG)